# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: '.predictImage()' has been deprecated! Please use 'classifyImage()' instead

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, imageai

So I followed this blog to build Image Classification using ML,
I had trained for 2 datasets, dogs and Pipes, and no matter which image I give it, it always says its 100% pipes with the following error,

```
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
c:/Users/user1/Projects/firstCustomImageRecognit.py:12: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: '.predictImage()' has been deprecated! Please use 'classifyImage()' instead.
  predictions, probabilities = prediction.predictImage("12.jpeg", result_count=3)
Pipes  :  100.0
dogs  :  0.0
```

Can anyone tell what needs to be done

Comment: Even title says that's a warning, not an error. And it tells you what to do exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As the Warning suggest use `classifyImage()` inplace of `predictImage()`, which is removed in latest version.

You can suppress the warning messages using

```
import logging, os
logging.disable(logging.WARNING)
os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"
```